# Calculation of effect size for Wald Chi square in GLM

Tags: generalized-linear-model, spss, chi-squared-test

I am using GLM in SPSS for a real world data set. Disaster damage (continuous) vs regime types (categorical). This could be ANOVA, but as the DV is highly positively skewed with a lots of zero, I decided to go with compound-poisson and using GLM. 
My question is how could I report better way, as there is no effect size estimate in wald chi test in GLM? (my df = 4 )